# SSRS - Is there a better way to do this expression?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a line chart and one of the series expressions look like this:

```
=IIF((DateDiff("dd", Fields!EstimatedImpDt.Value, Fields!ActualImpDt.Value) = 0)
     ,100
     ,(100 - (((DateDiff("dd", Fields!EstimatedImpDt.Value, Fields!ActualImpDt.Value)) 
                / (DateDiff("dd", Fields!CreateDt.Value, Fields!EstimatedImpDt.Value))) 
                * 100
             )
      )
     )
```

I've checked to make sure there is data in each field, and I've checked to make sure the Parenthesis are all in the correct spot. Some of them may not be 100% necessary but I believe they are. It doesn't look like a calculated series would work. Is there anything visibly wrong with the expression? Is there a more effective way of doing this?

EDIT:

So I think Timeline Score, which gets its value from this expression is returning as a date, which is why it isn't showing up in the report when I run the page that contains the report. I tries using =CInt(Format()) around the whole expression but that didn't work.

here is a screenshot of what is going on:

[image]

I only have one row in the database but there should still be a point on the chart for this value.

EDIT 2: So I figured it out. For some reason using "dd" wasn't working. So I switched it to DateInterval.Day and it works perfect now!

Comment: What value are you expecting? Because it might well be negative if I look at the expression. Is the Y-axis of the graph automatically determined?

Have you tried putting the expression in a textbox/matrix and see what values it returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expressions looks OK. You do have some extra sets of parenthesis.

I think your IIF should check the DENOMINATOR

```
DateDiff("dd", Fields!CreateDt.Value, Fields!EstimatedImpDt.Value)
```

of the expression rather than the NUMERATOR

```
DateDiff("dd", Fields!EstimatedImpDt.Value, Fields!ActualImpDt.Value)
```

to avoid DIV0 errors.

```
=IIF(DateDiff("dd", Fields!CreateDt.Value, Fields!EstimatedImpDt.Value) = 0, 100, 100 - (DateDiff("dd", Fields!EstimatedImpDt.Value, Fields!ActualImpDt.Value) / DateDiff("dd", Fields!CreateDt.Value, Fields!EstimatedImpDt.Value)) * 100)
```

Comment: If the numerator is a zero, it wouldn't go to that part of the expression though, It would return 100. I added some more details that I just noticed, any thoughts?